# $.getJSON stop working in google maps api distancematrix

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, google-maps

It was really strange because i have this code for months working fine but since the last week i can't use it anymore. The code was always the same:

```
   $.getJSON("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins="+origin+"&destinations="+destinations+"&mode=walking&language=es-ES&sensor=false", function(datos) {
            alert("hello");
                    // code
            }
        });
```

I can not even see the "hello" alert.
But i can see the json code, this is an example: [Example](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=Rivadavia%20200%20Canada%20de%20Gomez%20Santa%20Fe%20Argentina&destinations=Mitre%201489%20Canada%20de%20Gomez%20Santa%20Fe%20Argentina%7CJ.%20Hern%C3%A1ndez%20393%20Canada%20de%20Gomez%20Santa%20Fe%20Argentina%7CCentenario%201564%20Canada%20de%20Gomez%20Santa%20Fe%20Argentina%7CMaipu%201360%20Canada%20de%20Gomez%20Santa%20Fe%20Argentina%7CMaipu%2054%20Canada%20de%20Gomez%20Santa%20Fe%20Argentina%7CAvellaneda%20410%20Canada%20de%20Gomez%20Santa%20Fe%20Argentina&mode=walking&language=es-ES&sensor=false)

So, which may be the problem?

Comment: Perhaps you should check for returned errors. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740218/error-handling-in-getjson-calls

Comment: Thanks, but i can't catch the error description... If i use ".fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { alert('getJSON request failed! ' + textStatus); })" the "textStatus" just shows the word "error". And if i try to catch it with "$.ajax({
    url: 'url',
    dataType: 'json',
    error: function( data ) {
      alert( "ERROR:  " + data );
    }
  });"
       the "data" just shows [Object object], which is very common in these cases.

Comment: the "errorThrown" alert "NetworkError: A network error occurred."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's fine for you when it works for months, but your mistake is to rely on a fact that you can't rely on.

You are requesting the [**DistanceMatrix-Webservice**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distancematrix/) via Javascript, but you've ignored this note in the documentation:

**Looking to use this service in a JavaScript application? Check out the [`DistanceMatrixService`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/services#distance_matrix) class of the Google Maps API v3.**

The Webservice doesn't support JSONP, and he currently didn't send an appropriate `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`-header(that's the fact you did rely on and that is required to access this Service via AJAX, but the documentation didn't say that this header will be sent), so **this Service can't be requested reliable via AJAX/Javascript**.

In google-chrome the console e.g. will tell you this:
***XMLHttpRequest cannot load [URL]. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin '[URL]' is therefore not allowed access.***

Comment: Thanks! But, what do you recommend me to use? The Distance Matrix javascript function doesn't work for me (it didn't recognize some countries and places to calculate the distance and i need to fix it). Probably i should use the service in php, but it maybe have the same problem. I don't know other way to use the service

Comment: What should I recommend? When the services didn't give you the desired result you must look for other service-providers

Comment: The webservice and the [Google Maps Javascript API v3 Directions Matrix service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/distancematrix) should return the same results (they use the same data), if the javascript service doesn't work because of data issues, the web service probably won't work either.