# jQuery $.getJSON does not return key and value pairs

Tags: jquery, json, getjson

I have a js file. In this file I am trying to `getjSON` data from the serverside. The json which returns from the server side is

```
{"STATUS":"TRUE","DEVICE_KEY":"80147459","ERROR_MESSAGE":""}
```

The script below do not return any alert. What am I doing wrong? (I checked if jQuery and jQueryMobile is loaded. there is no problem)

The same script works on my local machine but doesn't work on the distance server. Can this be an apache or php setup problem?

thanks

```
$(window).load(function () {
    $.getJSON("http://.... myfile.php", function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (k, v) {
            alert("key: " + k + "  val:" + v);
        })
    });
});
```

Comment: cross-domain ajax maybe

Comment: It is possible that the $.getJSON  function returned an error ?
[Try this question][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740218/error-handling-in-getjson-calls

Comment: can't u use a simple string ? a.g.   key-value  
and split it afterwards :)

Comment: the same php exists on my localhost. the script works on my local machine but doesn't work on the remote server. Is there a server setting that I am missing?

Comment: Dieter this one was the most easies sample. I have more complicated samples :) the problem is, it doesn't work on the distance server at all. Do I have to change any php or apache setting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a cross-domain problem.

I used jsonp and it worked.. see http://json-p.org/

Answer (score 1):

I think you are not parsing it.

The JSON is just a Javascript Object Notation and it is a string. You'll have to parse it to convert it to a object.

Do this:

```
$(window).load(function () {
    $.getJSON("http://.... myfile.php", function (data) {
        data = JSON.parse(data); // add this line
        $.each(data, function (k, v) {
            alert("key: " + k + "  val:" + v);
        })
    });
});
```