# How to check for error 403

Tags: json, google-sheets, http-status-code-403, status

I am using the following script to get data from a Google Spreadsheet. From time to time the spreadsheet will be 'turned off' and the script will result in an error 403. I want to know how to check for that error and trigger another function when it does.

```
function loadJSON0() {
    $(function checkJSON0() { 
        $.getJSON( https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/SPREADSHEETKEY/1//public/values?alt=json-in-script&callback=?,
        function (data) {
            $.each(data.feed.entry, function(i,entry) {
                // do stuff
            });
        });
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Posible duplicate : [Error handling in getJSON calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740218/error-handling-in-getjson-calls)

```
$.getJSON("https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/SPREADSHEETKEY/1//public/values?alt=json-in-script&callback=?", function() {
    $.each(data.feed.entry, function(i,entry) {
        // do stuff
    });
})
.error(function() { alert("error"); });
```

Comment: this solution throws an additional error. "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ."

Comment: Please proide the whole error.
Also can you provide the entire http response?

Comment: the original error appears as:     jquery.min.js:4 GET https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/14nscmFGq1EEaXBT0ybSqar_ij3d1_SnusbeJSXR9aH4/1/public/values?alt=json-in-script&callback=jQuery32109224964495020795_1507201568433&_=1507201568434 net::ERR_ABORTED