# JQuery Ajax response not triggering success

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

This is my code,

```
$.ajax({
            type:"get",

            //this doesn't work
            //url:'http://example.com/json.php',

            //But this works
            url:'http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags=cat&tagmode=any&format=json&jsoncallback=?',

            dataType:"jsonp",
            success:function(data){
                alert('success');
            },
            error:function(){
                alert('error');
            } 
});
```

in json.php I have

```
<?php
header("Content-type: application/javascript");
?>
```

Then I've copied all the output of that flickr url. So the problem shouldn't be in the content of my code but how it's being sent. What do i need to fix here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You say it does not work but what does it do?  What is returned from your php page?

Comment: Oh right, it does nothing, it returns neither the success alert or the error one. I've tried it with my local server also with the same results.

Comment: Sounds like another SO question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2380551/jquery-success-function-not-firing-using-jsonp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery calls the `success` callback for JSONP requests as pointed out by Nick Craver.

Have you added the callback into your PHP script?

Take a look at this article:
http://remysharp.com/2007/10/08/what-is-jsonp/

In your `json.php` file, you should be doing something like:

```
<?php
$jsonstuff = '{ something: "somethingHere" }';
echo $_GET['callback'] . "(" . $jsonstuff . ")";
?>
```

Since the default JSONP callback in jQuery is `callback`.

This is because jQuery appends a callback with an random string name (unless you specify it as `jsonpCallback` in the options. [More information can be found in the documentation.](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)
You won't see the callback appended because it's not part of the URL, it's added by jQuery only during the execution of the `$.ajax` method.

You can see what I mean by trying:
http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags=cat&tagmode=any&format=json&jsoncallback=myCallBackHandler

If the handler does not execute, jQuery does not trigger the success and complete handlers specified in the `$.ajax` options.

Comment: This is not accurate, the jsonp callback is just hooked up in a different way and place, it constructs a temporary function auto-named for this.  The `success` function **is**, by default, that callback (this includes `complete` as well). http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax.js#L213

Answer (score 0):

The correct **Content-type** for a JSON file is:

```
  header( 'Content-type: application/json' );
```

Could that be the problem?

Comment: No - the official documentation states that it should be "application/json".
See the following:
 - http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt
 - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON
 - http://mimeapplication.net/json