# Response OK but success metod on $.ajax not fire?

Tags: php, html, ajax

```
        $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
            var fields = $("#testform").serializeObject();
            var response = "Nista";
            JSONstring = JSON.stringify(fields);
            alert(JSONstring);

            $.ajax({
                type: "GET", 
                url: "http://localhost/testSimple.php?symbol=IBM&jsonpCallback=?",
                // url: "http://localhost/testSimple.php?json=" + JSONstring,
                dataType: "jsonp", 

                success: function (msg) {
                    alert("SUCCESS");
                },
                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(textStatus);
                }
            });
```

in html:

```
<div id="dynamicContent" class="dynamicContent">
            <form id="testform" method="post">
            <div class="fm-req">
                <h2>
                    The Form:</h2>
            </div>
            <!--<input type="text" name="message" id="Text1" name="Fieldname22" />-->
            </form>
            <div class="fm-add">
                <input id="btnSubmit" type="button" value="Submit" />
            </div>
        </div>
```

and php script

```
<?php
$person = array(
        'name'    => 'Quentin',
        'country' => 'Australia'
    );

    header('Content-type: application/json');

    echo json_encode($person);
?>
```

in firebug is all right but succes not catches response..
WHY?

Comment: please reformat the code in your question, I can't read the form code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery success function not firing using JSONP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2380551/jquery-success-function-not-firing-using-jsonp)

Comment: BTW why not using [getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) instead?

Answer (score 2):

Try changing your PHP script to this:

```
<?php
$jsonpCallback = $_GET['jsonpCallback'];
$person = array(
        'name'    => 'Quentin',
        'country' => 'Australia'
    );

    header('Content-type: application/json');

    echo $jsonpCallback.'('.json_encode($person).')';
?>
```

#### Update for your question in the comments:

Your JavaScript should be like this:

```
$("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
    var fields = $("#testform").serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET", 
        url: "http://localhost/testSimple.php?"+fields+"&jsonpCallback=?",
        dataType: "jsonp", 

        success: function (msg) {
            alert("SUCCESS");
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(textStatus);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you - alert (Success). Another question - how to change my php for  url: "http://localhost/testSimple.php?json=" + JSONstring in $.ajax ?(commented url in original post)

Comment: @user816153: You are welcome. If my answer solved your problem, please consider accepting it by clicking on the tick below the vote counts on the left of my answer.

Comment: @user816153: If this answer is correct, and has solved the problem, please click the checkmark beside it to mark it as such. This will reward Shef for his help, and allow anyone viewing the question (and may be having similar problems) to quickly identify the solution.

Comment: @user816153: Updated my answer with a solution to your second problem. :)

Comment: Last question :) .How iterate throw json in php where the unknown values ?

Comment: @user816153: I don't get your last question. However, I think it's best for you to ask your additional questions in separate questions, not in the comments, because it will help others as well.

Answer (score 0):

remember that `jsonp` doesn't work on localhost!

but:

you have to add these line to your php code;

```
header("access-control-allow-origin: *");
header('content-type: application/json; ');
```

change your dataType to this in localhost mode:

```
dataType:'json'
```

and for testing the result do this on your ajax request:

```
    success: function(data, success) {
      console.log("success", arguments);
      console.log("data", typeof data, data); // Verify the response
    },
    error: function(jqxhr, textStatus, error) { 
      console.log("error", arguments);
    },
    complete: function(jqxhr, textStatus) {
      console.log("complete", arguments);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to change datatype to json

```
dataType: "json",
```

If you want to use callback do it like this

```
$.ajax({
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  data: 'id=10',
  jsonp: 'jsonp_callback',
  url: 'http://myotherserver.com/getdata',

  success: function () {
    // do stuff
  },
});
```

Here i found a good article on jsonp 
http://remysharp.com/2007/10/08/what-is-jsonp/

Comment: Why change it to `json`? S/he is doing cross-domain ajax request.

Comment: jquery only supports four datatypes check this out http://docs.jquery.com/Specifying_the_Data_Type_for_AJAX_Requests

Comment: @Varun Mittal: How about you check the [`$.ajax()` docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) about the `dataType` it accepts?

Comment: @Varun - not according to this section which is pulled directly from the $.ajax documentation - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ (scroll to dataType).  Jsonp appears to be a valid datatype now.

Comment: "jsonp": Loads in a JSON block using JSONP. Will add an extra "?callback=?" to the end of your URL to specify the callback.