# syntax error when trying to use backbone.js with Facebook json feed

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a super simple Backbone model/collection that wraps around a facebook feed.

```
window.Story = Backbone.Model.extend({});
window.Stories = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: Story,
  url: 'https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=186424828078649&format=json&callback=?',
  parse: function(response) {
    console.log(response);
    return response.entries;
  }
});

stories = new Stories();
stories.fetch();
```

This results in a syntax exception in Chrome ("Unexpected token :"), or in Firefox, an invalid label `"title": {`.

The Chrome message is a little cryptic, but the Firefox message seems to indicate that the JSON response is being returned. the `parse()` function is never getting called (as far as I can tell, I've set a breakpoint and added a console.log statement and I'm not seeing anything), so is there anything else that Backbone needs to know in order to parse JSON?

My first thought was that it might be a Cross-Domain issue, but I'm using `&callback=?` which should make sure that $.ajax uses jsonp. I'm betting that this is working, because Firefox is identifying the 2nd line correctly as `"title": {`.

Any ideas?

PS, jsfiddle is at http://jsfiddle.net/KcE9L/ if you'd like to test things out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out after some deep debugging. It's because Facebook ignores/doesn't support JSONP, and leaves me with this problem: [Jquery success function not firing using JSONP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2380551/jquery-success-function-not-firing-using-jsonp). Now I need to figure out how to get CORS working with Facebook, so if anybody can help me along those lines, I'd be curious.

Comment: I ended up using the social graph... not quite as easy as I'd like, but not too difficult.