# jsonp issue - success function doesn't execute

Tags: jquery, jsonp

I'm trying to read a simple json on an external server.  In the Firebug Net Panel, I'm seeing the correct data in the Response and JSON tabs.  But the success function doesn't execute.

The Callback is showing as: `fullurl?callback=jQuery1710837256851301949_1334637212326&_=1334638519052` and not as a function - not sure why - could this be the issue?

My code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "external url",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    data : {},
    success: function (data) {
        console.log('success');
        alert("success");
        //   var myname = data.name;
        //   var myid = data.id;
        //     var fullcontent= "Name: " + myname + " ID: " + myid;
        // $("#jsondata").html(fullcontent);
    }
});
```

Please help - thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the callback function as jsonpCallback not as success.

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "external url",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        data : {},
        jsonpCallback: function (data) {
            console.log('success');
            alert("success");
        }
});
```

**Edit**:

For JSONP to work properly, the server should directly write the JSON data in the stream. It should not print the JSON string. More details in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2380551/jquery-success-function-not-firing-using-jsonp).

I am assuming that you are writing in the stream properly in the server. Is that is the case?

Comment: Thanks Sudar - but it still doesn't work.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: data in jsonpCallback function comes up undefined for me.  How to get around this?