# Success function does nothing

Tags: json, jquery, jsonp

I try to obtain data from a json, using $.ajax, but my success function function does nothing.

This is my code:

```
     $.ajax({ 
     url: "http://gbrds.gbif.org/registry/organisation/15b278a8-1356-4f7b-ba32-3c733c3d0aac.json?op=contacts",
     jsonp: false,
     jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
     cache: 'true',
     dataType : 'jsonp',
     success: function(data) {
         alert("!");
         console.log("!");
       },
 });
```

Status code in chrome is 200 OK

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery success function not firing using JSONP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2380551/jquery-success-function-not-firing-using-jsonp)

Answer (score 1):

you are trying to make a jsoncallback instead of success.  I found this out by adding the 'error:' case in your ajax. I removed the callback, and you were good to go!

```
$.ajax({ 
     url: "http://gbrds.gbif.org/registry/organisation/15b278a8-1356-4f7b-ba32-3c733c3d0aac.json?op=contacts",    
    // jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
     cache: 'true',
     dataType : 'jsonp',
     success: function(data) {
         alert("!");
         console.log("!");
       },
    error:function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
     alert("error: "+ textStatus);   
    }
 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xKq4Y/

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$.ajax({ 
     url: "http://gbrds.gbif.org/registry/organisation/15b278a8-1356-4f7b-ba32-3c733c3d0aac.json?op=contacts",
     jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
     dataType : 'jsonp',
     success: function(data) {
         console.log("!");
         console.log(data);
      }
 });
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zYSSk/)