# Jquery ignore error and success json code

Tags: android, jquery, json, cordova

I trying consume service with phonegap and android.

My service using localhost return the json with chrome:

```
{
    "GetListaMunicipiosResult": [{
        "MunicipioID": "1",
        "MunicipioNome": "Florianópolis",
        "MunicipioUf":"SC"
    }, {
        "MunicipioID": "2",
        "MunicipioNome": "Jaraguá do Sul",
        "MunicipioUf": "SC"
    }]
}
```

In my `.js` file, I call the GET json with the code:

```
$('#cidades_page').live('pageshow',function(event){
    $.ajax("http://10.0.2.2:56976/MunicipiosService.svc/ListaMunicipios",{
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();
        alert("beforeSend");
        },

        complete: function () {
            // $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
            alert("complete");
        },
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        jsonp: "callback",
        type: "GET",
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert(xhr.status);
            alert(xhr.responseText);
            //alert(thrownError);
        },
        success: function (data) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(data));

        }
    });
});
```

But when page show, only alert alert("beforeSend") fired, and after nothing happens.

I insert the json call in html using  $.ajax(....  and open with chrome and its work. I do not know what else to do.

thanks for help

EDIT
I test in windows phone and now i can get error Error:GetListaMunicipios was not called.

My .js:

```
$.ajax("http://localhost:56976/MunicipiosService.svc/ListaMunicipios?callback=?",{
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            // $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();
        alert('beforeSend');
        },

        complete: function () {
            // $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
            alert('complete');
        },
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        crossDomain: true,
        jsonp: 'callback',
        jsonpCallback:'GetListaMunicipios',
        type: 'GET',
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert(xhr.status);
            alert(xhr.responseText);
            alert(thrownError);
        },
        success: function (data) {
            alert('success');

        }
    });
```

My WCF Service

namespace GuiaService
{

```
[ServiceContract]

public interface IMunicipiosService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
        UriTemplate = "ListaMunicipios")]

    List<ClsListaMunicipios> GetListaMunicipios();
}
```

}

thanks for help.

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2380551/jquery-success-function-not-firing-using-jsonp

Answer (score 1):

You should use `done`, `fail` and `always`.

`success`, `error` and `complete` are deprecated.

Update: as noted in the comments, this isn't true for how you're using it. I now believe the problem is because you're using `jsonp` as the type instead of `json`.

`jsonp` is designed to call a function automatically when loaded, so your server should be adding a function call to the generated code. It's possible that jQuery expects this behaviour and disables its own callbacks, or uses the `jsonp` mechanism to trigger its own callbacks, but since your server doesn't actually add the function call, nothing happens.

Comment: Since when?  Can you provide a link? (not doubting you, just haven't seen that yet)

Comment: @Steve Deprecated in 1.8, as stated in the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ Possibly (probably) removed in 1.9 / 2.0

Comment: Well, this states that the `jqXHR.success()` method is removed, not the `success` callback within the settings object.

Comment: @Steve so it does. I've always set up properties in the object and assumed they were the same in the parameters. I'll fix my answer.