# How to callback a function on 404 in JSON ajax request with jQuery? 

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, http-status-code-404

I want to make an Ajax request with response in JSON. So I made this Ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://my_url',
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){
      alert('success');
    },
    error: function(data){
      alert('error');
    },
    complete: function(data) {
      alert('complete')
    }})
```

This code works good but when my url send me a HTTP code 404, no callbacks are used, even the complete callback.
After research, it's because my dataType is 'json' so 404 return is HTML and the JSON parsing failed. So no callback.

Have you a solution to call a callback function when a 404 is raised ?

EDIT: complete callback don't call is return is 404. If you want an URL wit 404 you can call : http://twitter.com/status/user_timeline/jksqdlmjmsd.json?count=3&callback=jsonp1269278524295&_=1269278536697 it's with this URL I have my problem.

Answer (score 20):

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://twitter.com/status/user_timeline/jksqdlmjmsd.json?count=3&callback=jsonp1269278524295&_=1269278536697',
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
        alert('success');
    },
    error: function(data) {
        alert('error');
    },
    complete: function(xhr, data) {
        if (xhr.status != 0)
             alert('success');
        else
             alert('fail');
    }
})
```

Comment: don't you mean: "complete: function(status, text){"

Comment: I try too, but complete callback it's not call too :(

I update my question with this solution and more explain

Comment: it's same. if you made an alerte just in function of complete, it's not call.

Comment: Huh? It is for me. I copied your code and it worked, I just expanded to show how you would handle. Use Firebug and see your requests/responses. Possible JS error somewhere.

Comment: i'm using codeigniter and it's just ignoring all the callbacks, the web inspector is showing a 404 error.

Comment: @Mfoo, what is lazy about this? 5 year old jQuery code that I think was pulled from their documentation in the first place.

Answer (score 9):

With your configuration jQuery uses [jsonp](http://bob.pythonmac.org/archives/2005/12/05/remote-json-jsonp/) to transport the data. This works by dynamically inserting a script element and setting the URL to the specified value. The data returned by the server is then evaluated as JavaScript - usually calling the provided callback. If the server returns a 404, the contents is obviously no JavaScript and the callback is never called. Some browsers support error handlers on the script tag, which are called in these situations. Unfortunately IE doens't support this. The best way to detect an error is to rely on a timeout.

In your case you should specify an additional `timeout` option, which causes the error handler to be called if the callback wasn't called in time (which would be the case for a 404 response).

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://my_url',
  timeout: 2000, // 2 seconds timeout
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(data){
    alert('success');
  },
  error: function(data){
    alert('error');
  },
  complete: function(data) {
    alert('complete')
  }
});
```

Comment: The timeout not resolved solution. Call nothing after pass :(

Comment: Same here, mine just triggers the error everytime although it gets the data.

Comment: Not sure what this answer is doing all the way down here on -1.

Answer (score 5):

Use the `statusCode`-Option

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://my_url',
    dataType: "json",
    statusCode: {
        404: function() {
            alert("I could not find the information you requested.");
        }
    },
    success: function(data) {
      alert('success');
    },
    error: function(data) {
      alert('error');
    },
    complete: function(data) {
      alert('complete');
    }
})
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to handle errors when accessing the Twitter API with Javascript and jsonp you need to include the parameter `suppress_response_codes` in your request. This makes all responses from the Twitter API respond with a `200 OK` response and include a error. Then you need to check if the response includes the `error` parameter or not.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "https://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.json",
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  jsonp: "callback",
  data: {
    screen_name: "simongate1337",
    suppress_response_codes: true // <- Important part
  },
  success: function(data) {
    if(data.error) {
      console.log("ERROR: "+data.error);
    } else {
      console.log("Success, got user " + data.screen_name);
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Do not you think that the problem is not with the dataType but with cross-domain requests that you are not allowed to make?

The code below works as expected when you request data from the same domain and does not when you are making cross-domain requests:

```
function handle404(xhr){
    alert('404 not found');
}

function handleError(xhr, status, exc) {
     // 0 for cross-domain requests in FF and security exception in IE 
    alert(xhr.status);
    switch (xhr.status) {
        case 404:
            handle404(xhr);
            break;
    }
}

function dumbRequest() {
    var url = 'http://twitter.com/status/user_timeline/jksqdlmjmsd.json?count=3&callback=jsonp1269278524295&_=1269278536697';
    url = 'http://twitter.com/';    
    url = '/mydata.json';    
//    url = 'mydata.json';    
    $.ajax(
        {url: url,
         dataType: 'json',
         error: handleError}
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is it simply because the `dataType` is set to "json"?  If so, try changing it to `text` and evaluate the JSON yourself:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://twitter.com/status/user_timeline/jksqdlmjmsd.json?count=3&callback=jsonp1269278524295&_=1269278536697',
    dataType: 'text',
    success: function(data, status, xmlHttp) {
        try {
            data = eval('(' + data + ')');
            alert('success');
        } catch (e) {
            alert('json parse error');
        }
    },
    error: function(xmlHttp, status, error) {
        alert('error');
    },
    complete: function(xmlHttp, status) {
        alert('complete');
    }
});
```

Comment: This failed even it's works like on URL http://twitter.com/status/user_timeline/shingara.json?count=3&callback=jsonp1269278524295&_=1269278536697

Comment: What if you try it without the `callback=jsonp...` in the URL?  For example: http://twitter.com/status/user_timeline/shingara.json?count=3&_=1269278536697

Answer (score 1):

Are you aware that even though the HTTP status is 404, the actual body is valid JSON? For instance, [this link](http://twitter.com/status/user_timeline/jksqdlmjmsd.json?count=3&callback=jsonp1269278524295&_=1269278536697) has the following JSON:

`jsonp1269278524295({"request":"/status/user_timeline/jksqdlmjmsd.json?count=3&callback=jsonp1269278524295&_=1269278536697","error":"Not found"})`

As such, you should check if your data has the `error` property within your normal callback function.

**UPDATE**: apparently, even though the actual content of the page is valid JSON, the browser (I checked in Firefox) is not executing it, most likely because it is a 404. Because jQuery has to add a `script` element (because of the cross-domain issue), its JSONP wrapper is never called, and as a consequence, neither are your callbacks.

So, in short, I don't think there is a way to deal with this without manually adding that script element and checking if your pre-defined callback function has been called afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

Just faced the same issue, and saw [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309953/how-do-i-catch-jquery-getjson-or-ajax-with-datatype-set-to-jsonp-error-wh) mentioned that [jQuery-JSONP (jQuery Plugin)](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-jsonp/)  supports catching 404 errors or as they describe: "*error recovery in case of network failure or ill-formed JSON responses"*

And it works perfect :)

Here is my (simplified) code for fetching details about a YouTube video via JSONP:

```
$.jsonp(
{
    url: "https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/ee925OTFBCA",
    callbackParameter: "callback",
    data: 
    {
        alt: "jsonc-in-script",
        v: "2"
    },
    success: function(json, textStatus) 
    { 
        console.log("WEEEEEEEE!"); 
    },
    error: function(xOptions, textStatus) 
    {
        console.error(arguments);
    }
});
```

Comment: This is a great solution to the actual question asked.  It's a shame the library seems to have stopped being developed.  Is there a similar solution for modern versions of jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I deal with this. I check the returned data for errors before trying to use it. What is shown below is just a sample that you could extend to more closely match your requirements.  This also considers session time outs and other scenarios...

My initial call:

```
  $.ajax({ type: 'POST', 
    url: '../doSomething',
    data: 'my data',
    success: function(data) {
      if (HasErrors(data)) return;
      var info = eval('(' + data + ')');
      // do what you want with the info object
    },
    error: function(xmlHttpRequest) {
      ReportFailure(xmlHttpRequest);
    }
  });
```

And the two helper functions:

```
function HasErrors(data) {
  if (data.search(/login\.aspx/i) != -1) {
    // timed out and being redirected to login page!
    top.location.href = '../login.aspx';
    return true;
  }
  if (data.search(/Internal Server Error/) != -1) {
    ShowStatusFailed('Server Error.');
    return true;
  }
  if (data.search(/Error.aspx/) != -1) {
    // being redirected to site error reporting page...
    ShowStatusFailed('Server Error. Please try again.');
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

and

```
function ReportFailure(msg) {
  var text;
  if (typeof msg == 'string') {
    text = msg;
  }
  else if (typeof msg.statusText == 'string') {
    if (msg.status == 200) {
      text = msg.responseText;
    }
    else {
      text = '(' + msg.status + ') ' + msg.statusText + ': ';
      // use the Title from the error response if possible
      var matches = msg.responseText.match(/\<title\>(.*?)\<\/title\>/i);
      if (matches != null)
      { text = text + matches[1]; }
      else
      { text = text + msg.responseText; }
    }
  }
  // do something in your page to show the "text" error message
  $('#statusDisplay')
    .html('<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert"></span>' + text)
    .addClass('StatusError');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following solution is working fine for me :)

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://my_url',
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){
      alert('success');
    },
    error: function(data){
      alert('error');
    },complete: function(xhr, data) {
        if(data==="parsererror"){
             alert('404');
        }
    } 
});
```