# jquery not able to handle 404 error with twitter api

Tags: jquery, twitter

Below is my code

```
var tweetid = '133450847156838400';
        $.ajax({
                dataType: "jsonp",
                url: "http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/show/"+tweetid+".json?include_entities=1&callback=?",
                error:function(xhr, testStatus, error) {
                    alert("error");
                },
                success: function(html){
                    alert("success");
                }
            });
```

Chrome console shows me 404 error response but jQuery is not able to trigger the alert.

I added

```
        $(document).ajaxError(function(event, request, settings){
            alert('error');
        });
```

nothing happens. Can someone help me in handling this error as I have to detect if this tweet is deleted.

Comment: See my answer in [How to callback a function on 404 in JSON ajax request with jQuery? ][1] for information on how to solve it.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12093152/128280

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure (not entirely), that the dataType jsonp doesn't properly handle non-200 http status codes.  The reason is on jsonp actually works.  The wikipedia page explains it better: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP, but basically, jsonp amounts to appending a script element onto the page with the url you've given.  And the body of the script element is a function call.  If you get any status code != to 200, then that body will not be there and no function will be called (which eventually calls the callback functions).

So, if you continue to use jsonp, then you will need to have some kind of timeout in waiting for a response and expect that the request failed or some other method.

Comment: Can there be any other way? I see 404 status error in my browser console log. Isn't there a way to capture such a status response. i.e., capture 404 error whenever they occur.

Answer (score 1):

The [jQuery.fn.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)() page explains that `error: fxn()` is not called when using jsonp. Here is the blurb:

> Note: This handler is not called for cross-domain script and JSONP
>   requests. This is an Ajax Event.

The only solution I've heard of in this case is to utilize a proxy, which circumvents the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) and allows you to utilize error callbacks. I've never tried this, though, and don't feel qualified to give you advice on how to do it ;)

Comment: You mean to say get tweets from server and throw it on browser?
Thats a good suggestion and I want to do that but twitter has api limit of 150 tweets per hour. With fetching tweets client side would mean 150 per user but fetching from server would mean 150 overall. This is the main problem.