# Handling 404 bad request in getJSON() jquery

Tags: jquery, rest, jsonp

I have the following code and I am retrieving JSON from a site using JSONP. I want to handle error code like 404 bad request. Following is not working for me.

```
$.getJSON('https://xyz.com/search?jsonp-callback=?', function(data) {

  alert("success");
})
.success(function() { alert("success 2"); })
.error(function() { alert("error occurred "); })
.complete(function() { alert("Done"); });
```

Success and complete methods are working but error method is not working.

Comment: try to test same in $.ajax..

Comment: @DipeshParmar Not working. S

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: @JacoKoster jquery 1.8.2

Answer (score 6):

Try [`fail`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.fail/) instead of `error` (see the [Deferred doc](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/)).

Answer (score 4):

```
$.getJSON('https://xyz.com/search?jsonp-callback=?', function(data) {
  alert("success");
})
.success(function() { alert("success 2"); })
.error(function(event, jqxhr, exception) {
    if (jqxhr.status == 404) {
              alert("error occurred ");   
    }
})
.complete(function() { alert("Done"); });
```

Above code may help you.

Answer (score 1):

This thread has the answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/14371049/685925

Since you're using JSONP, the callback created by jQuery isn't called so the failure callback never gets called. That's the normal behavior for JSONP, alas.