# Remote JSONP datasource isn't working for me

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jsonp

no matter what i do, i couldn't get alert("test"); to display an alert. for some reason this jsonp (although it fetches the data correctly: http://u.kodingen.com/1JsHcN ) never calls the success function.

if i copy and paste the example here: http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp it works beautifully. but my URL doesn't.

any ideas?

```
        $("#venue_in").autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://x.com/y.php",
                dataType: "jsonp",
                data: request,
                cache: false,                
                success: function(data) {
                    alert("test");
                    response(data);
                }
            })
        },
        minLength: 2,
    });
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/309953/how-do-i-catch-jquery-getjson-or-ajax-with-datatype-set-to-jsonp-error-wh/310084#310084 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your URL doesn't seem to be returning valid JSONP.  It's not the same as JSON.

if your regular JSON url (`http://x.com/y.php`) returns JSON like this:

```
[{'label':'blah blah','value':3},{'label':'foo",'value':42}]
```

then the same JSONP url would look something like this:

```
`http://x.com/y.php?callback=myfunc`
```

and it would return something like this:

```
myfunc([{'label':'blah blah','value':3},{'label':'foo",'value':42}])
```

Your url dosn't appear to be including the 'P' part of JSONP.

[wikipedia's page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) isn't super-clear, but if you scroll down to the part on JSONP, and then read it carefully, it should make sense.   (If anyone has a better reference than wikipedia, please post it).

Comment: isn't that $.ajax's job to parse that into an arbitrary jsonp1234567 kind of callback function and get that as 'data' in success: function(data)?