# Why does $.getJSON silently fail?

Tags: jquery, json, error-handling, silent

It seems very inconvenient that jQuery's [`$.getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) silently fails when the data returned is not valid JSON. Why was this implemented with silent failure? What is the easiest way to perform getJSON with better failure behavior (e.g. throw an exception, `console.log()`, or whatever)?

Comment: While adequate answers were provided for my problem, I'm still baffled that the devs would program silent failure into `$.getJSON`...wtf jQuery guys?

Comment: It's because jQuery is *old*. Before JS had proper debugging tools, or even a console to log to, every failure was either silent, added to the page, or displayed in an `alert()`. Throwing exceptions would have halted the code, and prevented any possible recovery by client code later on; unless every bit of 3rd-party code were wrapped in a try-catch block by the developer.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

you can use

```
        function name() {
            $.getJSON("", function(d) {
                alert("success");
            }).done(function(d) {
                alert("done");
            }).fail(function(d) {
                alert("error");
            }).always(function(d) {
                alert("complete");
            });
        }
```

If you want to see the cause of the error, use the full version

```
function name() {
    $.getJSON("", function(d) {
        alert("success");
    }).fail( function(d, textStatus, error) {
        console.error("getJSON failed, status: " + textStatus + ", error: "+error)
    });
}
```

If your JSON is not well-formed, you will see something like

```
getJSON failed, status: parsererror, error: SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unrecognized token '/'
```

If the URL is wrong, you will see something like

```
getJSON failed, status: error, error: Not Found
```

If you are trying to get JSON from another domain, violating the [Same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy), this approach returns an empty message. Note that you can work around the Same-origin policy by using JSONP (which has it's [limitations](http://www.metaltoad.com/blog/using-jsonp-safely)) or the preferred method of Cross-origin Resource Sharing ([CORS](http://enable-cors.org/)).

Comment: Note that .error is deprecated - best to use .fail instead: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Why you will use this? instead of ajax? while this is a wrap for ajax method right? So basically would be better use Ajax when you want to handle all this "status".. what do you think?

Comment: @superluminary: use `fail(function(d, textStatus, error)...` I've just edited the answer.

Comment: In the case where this is a CORS-related issue (as it was in mine) you will get textStatus='error' and error='' so I'd called this a JSON fail in the design.  It should report something back to the developer in this case.  Adding the CORS-related response header for my server side fixed this issue and immediately allowed my client to now see the correct JSON returned.

Answer (score 29):

Straight from the documentation:

> **Important:** As of jQuery 1.4, if the JSON file contains a syntax error, the request will usually fail silently.

As the documentation page says, getJSON is simply a shorthand method for

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: 'json',
    data: data,
    success: callback
});
```

To get failure behavior, you can use $.ajax like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: 'json',
    data: data,
    success: callback,
    error: another callback
});
```

Comment: +1 the shorthand `$.getJSON` was convenient, but not flexible enough to be truly useful. /sigh.

Comment: The documentation is clear, but this doesn't explain _why_ it silently fails. What is the rationale behind the layer responsible for parsing a String into a JavaScript Object being silent about errors by default?

Comment: The shorthand is useful with the new promise syntax `$.getJSON(...).error(function() {...})`

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) instead, and set the `dataType` options to "json". From the documentation:

> "json": Evaluates the response as JSON
>   and returns a JavaScript object. In
>   jQuery 1.4 the JSON data is parsed in
>   a strict manner; any malformed JSON is
>   rejected **and a parse error is thrown**.
>   (See json.org for more information on
>   proper JSON formatting.)

Comment: +1 Apparently `$.ajax` also catches the parse error and sends information about it to the `error` callback, as mentioned by Håvard.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at the docs for this API... it has a .error on it.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Comment: The .success(), .error(), and .complete() callback methods introduced in jQuery 1.5 are deprecated as of jQuery 1.8.

Answer (score 0):

If you're requesting JSONP as the response, you will get a silent fail if there is no response (e.g. network outage). See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309953/how-do-i-catch-jquery-getjson-or-ajax-with-datatype-set-to-jsonp-error-w) for details.