# $.getJSON not doing anything

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am unsure why, but it seems that when I call $.getJSON after another getJson has been called, nothing happens.  Here is the code:

```
getWeather();

function getWeather() {
    $.getJSON("http://where.yahooapis.com/geocode?q=" + lat + ",+" + lon + "&gflags=R&flags=J", function(data){
        zipCode = data.ResultSet.Results[0].postal;
        WOEID = data.ResultSet.Results[0].woeid;
        getYahooWeather(WOEID);         
    });
}

function getYahooWeather(x) {
    var query = escape('select item from weather.forecast where woeid="'+x+'"');
    var url = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=" + query + "&format=json&callback=c";
    console.log(url);

    $.getJSON(url, function(data2){
        console.log("hey");
    });
}
```

My question is, am I doing something wrong with these $.getJSON calls?

Thanks so much

Comment: check your console for cross-domain-policy error

Comment: Is this question a possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5492838/why-does-getjson-silently-fail?

Comment: the console doesn't say anything.  it should say hey.  the first getJSON works fine.  the second one doesn't work

Comment: do those functions ever get called at all? do a `console.log()` for each, both before and after their `getJSON()`. check where the chain of execution cuts off.

Comment: in the first function, the console will show zipCode and WOEID.  in the second function it will show the url.  but it does not show hey

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have specified that the callback should be the `c` function, so declare it:

```
function getYahooWeather(x) {
  var query = escape('select item from weather.forecast where woeid="'+x+'"');
  var url = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=" + query + "&format=json&callback=c";
  console.log(url);

  $.getJSON(url);
}

function c(data2) {
  console.log("hey");
}
```

Comment: gahhhhhhhhhhhhh, that's what copying and pasting will do to you!!  thanks so much for telling me that!

Answer (score 1):

Your request is outside the current domain. You **cannot** make foreign request, it is restricted by cross-domain policy.

Such requests and made using a *jsonp* request instead. And here is a [guide](http://djpate.com/2011/02/25/how-to-make-cross-domain-ajax-request-using-jsonp-jquery/) to get you started.