# jQuery - Check if a .json file is valid

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am using a .json file and jQuery's `$.getJSON` to fill `div`s with text, my code for that looks like this:

Code:

```
  $.getJSON("/js/content.json", function (data) {
  $(".lander .title").text(data.lTitle);
  $(".lander .subtitle").text(data.lSubtitle);
  $(".lander .text").html(data.lText).split('\n').join('<br/>');
});
```

JSON File:

```
{
    "comment": "Landing page",
    "lTitle": "Your webpage",
    "lSubtitle": "Your webpage subtitle",
    "lText": "Edit this text under >js/content.json< ",

    "lDetailsTitle": "Here goes the details title under the landing header.",
    "lDetailsText": "Here goes the details text."

}
```

What I am trying to do is use `$parseJSON` to check if the whole `content.json` is valid (Not just one string). The reason I want to do this is so that jquery can display an error message in the DOM so the user is aware why there is no text in the `div`s.

I've tried this, but it is not working:

```
var isValid = jQuery.parseJSON("/js/content.json");
if (isValid === true) {} else {
    $("#overlayMessage").css("display", "block");
    $("#overlayMessage .title").text("Oh no, we can't display this page!");
    $("#overlayMessage .text").text("An error occured with the file under: 'js/content.json'. Reason: Invalid.");
}
```

Is this possible to do at all, or can you only check if one string is valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provide a `fail()` callback to catch parse errors coming out of `getJSON()`

```
$.getJSON('/foo/bar.json')
  .done(function(d) {
    alert("success");
  })
  .fail(function(d) {
    alert("error");
  });
```

Related: [Why does $.getJSON silently fail?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5492838/why-does-getjson-silently-fail)

Answer (score 2):

You probably want something like this:

```
try{
    var json = JSON.parse("invalid json");
}catch(err){
    console.log('json is invalid');
}
```

Output of running this in the browser is `json is invalid

Comment: This returns as invalid even if the json file is valid. (I checked.)

Comment: you checked invalid json it would seem. try something like `'{ "something":"1" }'`

Comment: What are you running it on, Sebastian? Must be a mistake. `JSON.parse("{}")` works for example.

Comment: Running it on.. what?

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery.parseJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/) parses a JSON string, but you've provided a URI. You could use [jQuery.get()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) to fetch the JSON as text, and then use `jQuery.parseJSON()` to check if it's valid.

```
$.get( "/js/content.json", function( data ) {
    try  {
        var jsonObj = jQuery.parseJSON( data );
    } catch(err) {
        $("#overlayMessage").css("display", "block");
        $("#overlayMessage .title").text("Oh no, we can't display this page!");
        $("#overlayMessage .text").text("An error occured with the file under: 'js/content.json'. Reason: Invalid.");
    }
});
```

Comment: This for some reason always returns as true, and I made the json invalid, doesn't seem to work.