# getJSON fails silently

Tags: javascript, json, getjson

I'm working with a project including placing some markers at a Leaflet map.
I use PostGIS to store the markers. I use Django as backend.
When I try to access the markers through a $.getJSON it files silently.

This is the code that fails:

```
function sendCategories(map){
    var checks = $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').map(function(){
               return $(this).val();
               }).get();
    var liste = JSON.stringify(checks);
    var categories ="{% url 'events:listEvents' 12345 %}".replace(/12345/,liste);
    $.getJSON(categories, function(data) {
        L.geoJSON(data).addTo(map);
    });

}
```

What is interesting is that I have this piece of code, that does simiar things, but works properly:

```
function addEvents(map) {
    var EventPoints = "{% url 'events:pointData' %}";
    $.getJSON(EventPoints, function (data) {
        L.geoJSON(data).addTo(map);
    });
}
```

Both of the urls haves the same data, I did check it multiple times.

When I try to log the error I get this:

```
getJSON failed, status: error, error:
```

Comment: i guessed you checked the JSON was correct? as [from the docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/): "As of jQuery 1.4, if the JSON file contains a syntax error, the request will usually fail silently"

Comment: From what I have understood the 

`console.error("getJSON failed, status: " + textStatus + ", error: "+error);`

should print something like this:

`etJSON failed, status: parsererror, error: SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unrecognized token '/'`
( from here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5492838/why-does-getjson-silently-fail )
but instead it prints

`getJSON failed, status: error, error: `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, it looks like the error with getJSON was caused by a form that refreshed the page. When I added `event.preventDeafult()` getJSON started to work.