# JSONP error in JQuery 1.7

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-domain, jsonp

**Note**: I've checked other answers including [this question re: a pre-jQuery 1.5 JSONP error issue that has now been resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309953/how-do-i-catch-jquery-getjson-or-ajax-with-datatype-set-to-jsonp-error-w). I am using JQuery 1.7 which I believe does not suffer from this issue.

As of [JQuery 1.5 **proper error functions are possible with JSONP**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) (see 'The jqXHR Object'). However the error function does not seem to be firing.

```
$.getJSON(url, function(response) { 
    console.log(response)   
}).error( function() { console.log('Error occurred.') } )
```

Looking at Chrome Dev Tools, the JSONP request generates the following error:

```
GET https://twitter.com/status/user_timeline/somepretendusername.json?count=2&callback=jQuery171005595548846758902_1334772179012&_=1334772179132 400 (Bad Request)
```

However the .error() callback simply does not seem to run. What do I need to get proper error handling working with JSONP?

Comment: Do you get the same result using the `.fail()` callback?

Comment: @KevinB Thanks. Alas .fail() does not seem to work either.

Answer (score 2):

The error function only triggers if there is an error with the request. The request is being made, but Twitter returns a 400 if the username doesn't exist. I tried it using a fake username and got the same response you did, but then I used my user name and it worked like a champ.

[edit] I see that you are just asking how to handle errors with JSONP. For whatever reason, it seems that jQuery doesn't have good error handling for this. I did find a plugin that promises to have actual error handling for JSONP. Check it out [here](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-jsonp/).

[edit2] Check it out, it works!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var url = 'https://twitter.com/status/user_timeline/thisisnotarealtwitterhandle.json?count=2&callback=?';
    var jqxhr = $.jsonp({
        url: url,
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response)
        }
    }).fail(function() { console.log('error'); });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm using a real username. My question is how to get proper error handling working, not how to avoid the 400 error.

Comment: @nailer I guess the real question is if a statuscode of 400 should really trigger an error within jQuery. You can use the `.always` callback and get the statuscode of the request, then if the statuscode is 400, do this, else do that.

Comment: Yeah, I think I better understand your question. It does seem to stem from the fact that an error is thrown when the $.getJSON isn't successful.