# $.getJSON get status

Tags: jquery, http-status-code-404, getjson

Perform cross domain query, how to perform a certain function if the URL on which it is running is not available (404)?
I try something like this:

```
$.getJSON({
url:'example.php?callback=?',
statusCode: {
404:function(){alert('404');}
},
success :function(data){//do stuff}
});
```

Comment: aren't you missing a `,` after your `url` parameter?

Comment: Did you read the documentation?

Comment: **Bruno Vieira** - no, I made ​​a mistake here, creating questions

Comment: **Lightness Races in Orbit** - Yes, I read it, but unfortunately the example given there was not helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Matt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1048862/matt) posted a great [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11799589/1812984) in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309953/how-do-i-catch-jquery-getjson-or-ajax-with-datatype-set-to-jsonp-error-w) that may solve your issue.

You will have to add a `success` property on your JSON object

```
var success = false;

$.getJSON(url, function(json) {
    success = true;
    // ... do what you need to do here
});

// Set a 5-second (or however long you want) timeout to check for errors
setTimeout(function() {
    if (!success)
    {
        // Handle error accordingly
        alert("Yup, 404"); // string was "Houston, we have a problem."
    }
}, 5000);
```

KeYan makes a good suggestion by checking the XHR status property if you aren't expecting timeout issues. <strike>I would vote his solution up, but I lack the rep points.</strike>

Comment: Did you add a `{'success':'true'}` ?

Comment: KeYan example does not work to... Maybe I'm doing something wrong? `var success = false; $.getJSON(sl+'/404/com.add.lics.php?callback=?',function(g){ success = true; }); setTimeout(function(){ if (!success){ alert("Houston, we have a problem."); } }, 5000);`

Comment: That's actually working correctly. You are successfully catching the delay within that if statement! Hitting the end of the timeout assumes your service is taking to long to respond, thus a 404.

Comment: Edited the string value to reflect what's actually happening, since the word 'problem' seemed to cause a bit of confusion

Comment: Ok, I tried to use this example with a different type of link and it works. Thank you!

Answer (score 33):

I found this approach to solve the similar question I had, where I wanted to handle specific status codes differently. For example the '404' code as below.

```
$.getJSON(AJAX_URL, function(data) {
    //On Success do something.

}).fail(function(jqXHR) {
    if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
        alert("404 Not Found");
    } else {
        alert("Other non-handled error type");
    }
});
```

There are 3 parameters passed to the fail method:

```
jqXHR.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {});
```

> An alternative construct to the error callback option, the .fail()
>   method replaces the deprecated .error() method. Refer to
>   deferred.fail() for implementation details.

For the jQuery docs see:
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR 
http://api.jquery.com/deferred.fail/

Comment: IMO this should be the accepted answer since it relies on a callback instead of relying on a pre-defined timeout for the response.

Answer (score 1):

```
 $.getJSON({
       url:'example.php?callback=?'       
    },
      success :function(data){//do stuff}
    })
    .error(function(e, x) { if (x.status == 404) alert('404 - page was not available'); });
```

Answer (score 0):

It is inherently impossible to get the status code of a JSONP request.

You can add a general error handler to the `$.ajax` call.