# How to get 406 Error (not acceptable) in jquery

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, getjson, mustache

I am doing error handling in my.js, where i am having cross domain call to other server, also for dynamic HTML template i am using Mustache.js.

```
$.getJSON(url, function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
  $.each(data, function(i, data) {
    introPage(data);
  });
}).fail(function(Error) {
        alert(Error.status);
}); 

function introPage(data )
{
    $.getJSON('myphp.php?jsoncallback=?&template='+testTemplate, function(msg) {
        // my operations

    }).error(function(data) {
            }); 
}
```

We have .fail() in getJSON to catch the errors in  [getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/). I am able to catch 404 error (not found) but when it comes to 406 error (not acceptable or say invalid input) or 401 error(unauthorised access), .fail() does not seems to work

but throws the error in console
[image: JSON ERROR IN CONSOLE]

Also when i click the link. it shows error in jquery callback in below format

```
jQuery191014790988666936755_1378113963780({
  "error": {
    "code": 406,
    "message": "Not Acceptable: Sorry, There are no results to display for the given input."
  }
});
```

Now i am wondering how to get this error in my JS . i am not getting Error code 406 and 401.I need that error code so that appropriate error page be displayed.

Thank you

Comment: You've been hit by, you've been struck by a smooth criminal. Also the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.com/wiki/Same-origin_policy)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan :  i dont understand ??? even though there is two server involved but both are under same domain !!! than why Same origin policy.

Comment: the subdomains are different. For AJAX requests, the domains muct be EXACTLY the same - down to the protocol.

Comment: @Rory: _Script and JSONP requests are not subject to the same origin policy restrictions._

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan : What i do understand is when i am making a call to my php 'url' using getJSON it is returning the error but it is not displaying me the error in .fail() because for some reason error is in jquery log or whatever .... so question how do i catch that error

Comment: @SalmanA obviously. But the OP is doing neither of those.

Comment: also @RoryMcCrossan : thanks .... but can u explain little bit in simple words about Same-origin policy

Comment: @SalmanA : ur right :)

Comment: @hitesh that's because the request works, but is blocked by the security policies of the browser. Therefore the `fail()` handler is never hit.

Comment: @SalmanA : jQuery v1.9.1

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan : so how do we handle it??

Comment: u mean something like this right 
 
    $.getJSON(url, function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
    $.each(data, function(i, data) {
    introPage(data);  
    });
    }).done(function(success) {
     console.log(success);
    });

Comment: @SalmanA  : sorry i dnt how to format it in SO comments

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan : lets assume you are right than what is way out of it ??? how do i catch those errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by the `jsoncallback=?` parameter and the response `jQuery191...780({...})`, it seems like jQuery is generating a JSONP request. JSONP requests are not subject to the same origin policy restrictions but they do have the following limitation [as described here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

> Note: This [error] handler is not called for cross-domain script and
>   cross-domain JSONP requests.

The solution:

1. Create a pure JSON request if the server allows cross-domain requests
2. Look at answers for these questions:

   - [How do I catch jQuery $.getJSON [...] error when using JSONP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/309953/87015)
   - [jQuery ajax (jsonp) ignores a timeout and doesn't fire the error event](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1002367/87015)
3. Use [jquery-jsonp](https://github.com/jaubourg/jquery-jsonp) -- it does not give you the HTTP error code

Comment: if i remove the jsoncallback=?

.......

i am getting error <code> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://example.com/myphp.php?&template=introPage.html. Origin http://myLocal is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. </code>
.......

Comment: I am afraid this is because of _Same Origin Policy_ in which case you must use JSONP in which case you cannot check for HTTP status.

Comment: so is there no way out of this ... i mean there should be something we can do .... there is always a solution to problem ?? @Salman A

Comment: If you control the other script (the one which sends JSON data or throws 404 errors) you can simply add [this header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Access-Control-Allow-Origin) to that script: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`. The other solution is to host a cross-domain proxy script on your server.