# How do I handle jQuery $.getJSON error responses when using JSONP?

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsonp

I have a RESTful app that returns HTTP 400 with an JSON-encoded reponse body when it encounters application errors:

```
Request URL:    http://.../middleware.php/entity/23.json?padding=jQuery20305847647329799524_1380182255277&_=1380182255278
Request Method: GET
Status Code:    HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request

Server: Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu)
Date:   Thu, 26 Sep 2013 07:57:36 GMT
Content-Type:   application/json
Content-Length: 133
```

Response body is valid JSONP according to FF:

```
jQuery20305847647329799524_1380182255277({"version":"0.2","exception":{"message":"Invalid UUID: '23'","type":"Exception","code":0}});
```

I'm trying to handle the failure:

```
$.getJSON("http://demo.volkszaehler.org/middleware.php/entity/23.json?padding=?").fail(
    function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
        console.error(JSON.stringify(jqXHR));
        console.error(jqXHR.responseText);
    }
);
```

Unfortunately, the jqXHR has only the following properties, both on FF25 and Chrome:

```
{"readyState":4,"status":404,"statusText":"error"}
```

The responseText itself shows as `""` and I'm unable to decode the action JSON response body.

**How can the actual JSON response body be parsed in the `fail()` method?**

Note: I've seen [How do I catch jQuery $.getJSON (or $.ajax with datatype set to 'jsonp') error when using JSONP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309953/how-do-i-catch-jquery-getjson-or-ajax-with-datatype-set-to-jsonp-error-w) but it seems to relate to catching the error at all, not about handling the error responses content.

Comment: I also find it consusing that jqXHR's status is 404 instead of 400...

Comment: JSONP is nothing else than dynamically including a `<script>` element. I assume if you set a response code other than `200`, the script won't be executed by the browser. I don't think there is a solution other than changing the response code, at least for JSONP requests.

Comment: Well- worst case I could always "eval" the script myself, but I don't even get the responseBody which should contain the script?!

Comment: As I said, JSONP is not a normal Ajax request. It works by simply adding a `<script>` element to the document and the browser downloads and executes the script. You don't have access to the actual request object. jQuery just provides a simplified version of the request object for consistency.

Comment: In any case jQuery gets 'data' back from the server. Where is that data? Why isn't even responseText returned, if not parsed as JSON?

Comment: jQuery doesn't directly get the data. It creates a dynamic function (`jQuery20305847647329799524_1380182255277`) and then waits that the script gets executed, which would call that function. Maybe reading the section "How JSONP works" in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11799589/218196) will clear things up for you.

Comment: I'm slowly getting it. JSONP includes a _remote_ script in the page that gets executed- but only when response is 200. So long story short- it's not possible :(

Comment: Yep :-/ That's why I said, if you have to serve JSONP, you should return a 200 status code and let the code handle the error case by inspecting the object. In all other cases, you can return a proper status code.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38087/discussion-between-andig-and-felix-kling)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Answer** (with help of @Felix Kling):

JSONP responses cannot bet received if JSONP server returns HTTP 400 status.

**Explanation:**

JSONP works by making the client include a remote (server-side) Javascript that produces the desired JSON response when being executed on the client side. In case of HTTP 400 the script never gets executed on client side.

**Workarounds:**

- Always return JSONP error messages/ exceptions with HTTP 200 OK, or
- Use Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS). When using jQuery on the client, the simplest way to enable CORS is to set an additional `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` header on the server.

For further reading on CORS see http://docs.kendoui.com/howto/use-cors-with-all-modern-browsers and http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/?redirect_from_locale=de#toc-cors-from-jquery