# Display markers Listview belong to same type ID

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

In my app I have three pages first page display types `listview` of markers (malls,supermarkets,etc..) , second page display markers `listview` that belong to same type, third page display details of each marker.

I have displayed the type page successfully , but the `listview` of markers with same type_ID not displayed!!

[image: page 1 type listview]

[image: page 2 markers listview]

> (landmarks table in DB)

```
**L_ID , name , image, Type_ID**
|1    , B_mall        , .jpg , 1|
|2    , c_mall        , .jpg , 1|
|3    , D_supermarket , .jpg , 2|
```

> php file query

```
<?php
    $dbhost = '127.0.0.1';
    $dbuser = 'root';
    $dbpass = '';
    $dbname = 'maalem';
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM landmarks where Type_ID=:id";

    try {
        $con = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass);  
        $con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $con->query('SET NAMES utf8');
        $stmt = $con->prepare($sql);  
        $stmt->bindParam("id", $_GET["Type_ID"]);
        $stmt->execute();
        $markers = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ); 
        $con = null;
        echo '{"items":'. json_encode($markers) .'}'; 
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}'; 
    }

?>
```

> types js file

```
 var serviceURL = "http://localhost/map/";            //192.168.1.157                                


var type;

$('#typeListPage').bind('pageinit', function(event) {
    gettypeList();
});

function gettypeList() {
    $.getJSON(serviceURL + 'gettype.php', function(data) {
        $('#typeList li').remove();
        type = data.type;
        $.each(type, function(index, type) {
            $('#typeList').append('<li><a href="marker.html?Type_ID=' + type.Type_ID + '">' +
                    '<img src="' + type.Icon + '"/>' +
                    '<h4>' + type.type_title + '</h4></a></li>');
        });
        $('#typeList').listview('refresh');
    });
}
```

> markers js file

```
 var serviceURL = "http://localhost/map/";                                           
 var markers;    
 $('#markerListPage').bind('pageinit', function(event) {
    getmarkerList();
});

function getmarkerList() {
    $.getJSON(serviceURL + 'getmarkers.php', function(data) {
        $('#markerList li').remove();
        markers = data.items;
        $.each(markers, function(index, landmarks) {
            $('#markerList').append('<li><a href="markerdetail.html?L_ID=' + landmarks.L_ID + '">' +
                    '<img src="pics/' + landmarks.Image + '"/>' +
                    '<h4>' + landmarks.Title + '</h4></a></li>');
        });
        $('#markerList').listview('refresh');
    });
}
```

> marker.Html File

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
   <header>
      <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
      <meta charset="utf-8">
   </header>
   <body>
      <div id="markerListPage" data-role="page" >
         <div data-role="header" >
            <h1>markers</h1>
            <a href="index.html" data-rel="back" class="ui-btn-left ui-btn  ui-btn-icon-notext ui-corner-all ui-icon-back"></a>
         </div>
         <div data-role="content">
            <ul id="markerList" data-role="listview"  data-filter="true"></ul>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not sure what to look for. Any errors in the console or network tab?

Comment: nothing shown in console , i have post an image of pages and i want to display the markers that have the same type in the page 2

Comment: You need to add Ajax error handling to see what is going on

Comment: please,can you you show me how to write the error handling in my js files ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/309953/how-do-i-catch-jquery-getjson-or-ajax-with-datatype-set-to-jsonp-error-w/310084#310084

Comment: I need to see the site. Send me the URL in email

Comment: ok ,, i send it

Comment: Why do you have two phps and two JS files - DRY - Do not repeat yourself.

Comment: Here is JS code that can update either: https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/58rj7d20/

Answer (score 1):

```
 var serviceURL = "http://localhost/map/";                                           
 var markers;    
 $('#markerListPage').live('pageshow', function(event) {
 var id = getUrlVars()["Type_ID"];
 $.getJSON(serviceURL + 'getmarkers.php?Type_ID=' + id, getmarkerList);

});

function getmarkerList(data) {
        $('#markerList li').remove();
        markers = data.items;
        $.each(markers, function(index, landmarks) {

            $('#markerList').append('<li><a href="markerdetail.html?L_ID=' + landmarks.L_ID + '">' +
                    '<img src="pics/' + landmarks.Image + '"/>' +
                    '<h4>' + landmarks.Title + '</h4></a></li>');
        });
        $('#markerList').listview('refresh');

}
```

Comment: If that solve your problem, try please to add a brief description, and mark it as correct answer for the future readers.