# Send info from Jquery to Php file on server to search SQL database

Tags: php

**I have this code located on the server in a php file**

```
<?php
include "db.php";
$data=array();
$idFacebook=$_POST['idFacebook'];

$q=mysqli_query($con,"select `gender` from `users` where 
`idFacebook`='$idFacebook'");
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_object($q)){
 $data[]=$row;
}
echo json_encode($data);

?>
```

**I have this code on my website**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var url = "http://xxxxxxxxx.com/calGetBackupJSON.php";
    $.getJSON(url, {idFacebook: 11111111111}, function(result) {
        console.log(result);

    });
});
```

Currently, I can manually change the `idFacebook` on the server and it returns the correct info. BUT
How do I pass the `idFacebook` from the web page to server? 
So it only returns one specific user's gender?

Thank you very much

Comment: [`$.getJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) *... using a GET HTTP request.*, so `$_POST` will not work.

Comment: following @Sean 's comment change `$_POST['idFacebook']` to `$_GET['idFacebook']` - __BUT__ please switch to prepared statements first. This is very unsecure.

Comment: Thank you I changed post to get and will look into prepared statements

Answer (score 1):

Add a HTML input Eg `<input type="text" id="idFacebook" />` and a button `<button id="submitIDFB"></button>` in your web page.

Change your JS content:

```
$('#submitIDFB').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var idFacebook = $('#idFacebook').val();
    var url = "http://xxxxxxxxx.com/calGetBackupJSON.php";
    $.getJSON(url, {idFacebook: idFacebook}, function(result) {
        console.log(result);

    });
});
```

You may do some data validation / data preparation first. :D

UPDATED:

If you want to handle error, use AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
  dataType: "json",
  url: url,
  data: {idFacebook: idFacebook},
  success: function(result) {
    console.log(result);

  },
  error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
    alert(xhr.status);
    alert(thrownError);
  }
});
```

Comment: It does not trigger any event. See its docs and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309953/how-do-i-catch-jquery-getjson-or-ajax-with-datatype-set-to-jsonp-error-w/310084#310084. If you want to handle error, you should use ajax.