# Check if Javascript process is already running

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Disclaimer:** I'm totally 'new' to javascript, so please excuse the absolute amateur code.

I have a progress bar script that polls a URL which dumps some json data. The script then updates a few html values based on the contents of said json, including a progress bar.

Here's a simplified version of the code:

```
function update_progress(status_url, index) {
  bar_id = document.getElementById(String('bar' + index));
  stage_id = document.getElementById(String('stage' + index));

  $.getJSON(status_url, function(data) {
    percent = parseInt(data['current'] * 100 / data['total']);

    // change progress bar and stage_id values
    bar_id.innerHTML = (percent + '%');
    bar_id.style.width = (percent + '%');
    stage_id.title = (data['status']);
    stage_id.value = (data['status']);
    stage_id.innerHTML = (data['status']);

    // if state is unexpected then end poll
    if (data['state'] != 'PENDING' && data['state'] != 'PROGRESS' && data['state'] != "COMPLETE") {
      stage_id.innerHTML = (data['state']);      

    // otherwise keep polling every 1.5 seconds
    } else {
      setTimeout(function() {
        update_progress(status_url, index);
      }, 1500);
    }
}
```

Sometimes the `status_url` can return a 500 error if the json data hasn't yet been compiled. So I have a button that restarts this poll by calling `update_progress` again.

**The problem:**
If a user clicks the 'restart poll' button, there will be two active polls for the same `status_url`.

There can be many polls ongoing at once to a bunch of different `status_url`'s - the more there are, the slower the response.

So I'd like to avoid being able to poll something that is already ongoing

**Question:** is there a way to check if a process with the same values is already ongoing in JS?

I'm aware that this is inefficient, and I'll be moving away from JS completely for this polling system at some point - however I need to do some quick efficiency patching on this current release before I get to that.

Thanks in advance

Comment: So do you have a way of ending the existing poll when the user clicks the 'restart poll' button?

Comment: could just throw in some console logs in different parts of the function executions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Cancelling a javaScript interval

You can assign `setTimeout` to a variable:

`var timer = setTimeout(...updateProgress...);`

And then, when the user clicks the button to refresh the poll, you can do:

`clearTimeout(timer)`

To delete the original timeout process, then create another one.

This answer your question I think. However:

#### There is no need to force the user to re-try the polling manually.

If the `getJson` call fails due to a 500 error, instead of clearing and launching the polling again, you can just keep polling. Now, I'm not used to `getJSON` syntax, but from what I read [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19075701/4166367),  you would do something like the following:

```
function update_progress(status_url, index) {
  bar_id = document.getElementById(String('bar' + index));
  stage_id = document.getElementById(String('stage' + index));

  $.getJSON(status_url, function(data) {
    percent = parseInt(data['current'] * 100 / data['total']);

    // change progress bar and stage_id values
    bar_id.innerHTML = (percent + '%');
    bar_id.style.width = (percent + '%');
    stage_id.title = (data['status']);
    stage_id.value = (data['status']);
    stage_id.innerHTML = (data['status']);

    // if state is unexpected then end poll
    if (data['state'] != 'PENDING' && data['state'] != 'PROGRESS' && data['state'] != "COMPLETE") {
      stage_id.innerHTML = (data['state']);      

    // otherwise keep polling every 1.5 seconds
    } else {
      setTimeout(function() {
        update_progress(status_url, index);
      }, 1500);
    }
  })
  .done(() => {}) // is this needed? I really don't know to be honest, 
  // maybe you can skip this right away
  .fail(() => {
    setTimeout(function() {
      update_progress(status_url, index);
    }, 1500); // we keep polling if the request fail!
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could separate your code on several callbacks, that would be executed on success, on failure, and other callback that would be executed always regardless of success or failure. You could then guess when the user clicks the submit button and disable it, then enable it again when the request is finished.

```
var ongoing = true; // Disable submit button
$.getJSON(status_url, function(data) {
  // Your success code here
})
.fail(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
  // Your error/retry code here
})
.always(function() {
   ongoing = false; // Enable submit button
});
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, much appreciated!